# How do you make the caption header's (a), (b), etc.. smaller when using subfigure?

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

I am using the subfigure package and a document I've been working on is essentially ready apart from an issue with the subfigure package. The header's (a), (b), etc.. in the captions are too large and I don't know how to reduce their size. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig_a.pdf}
\caption{\scriptsize First subfigure} \label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill} % separation between the subfigures
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig_b.pdf}
\caption{\scriptsize Second subfigure} \label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure that contains three subfigures} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks to me like your `\scriptsize` command is working correctly.  Do you want it smaller than that?  I think the only command smaller is `\tiny` but you can take a look at [this article](https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/) for the options.

Comment: It is the headers (a), (b), etc.. that I was concerned about, not the text in the caption itself.

Comment: Ah, I see.  My apologies, I misread it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add  in your preamble

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=scriptsize}
```

or, if it is only for the label:

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=scriptsize}
```